# Control to record user hotkeys in a OSX application

Tags: cocoa

I'm dealing with Hotkey registration, i can't found a way to make user able to register its hotkey. 
I tried ShortcutRecorder but it seems impossible to make it works, for me it crash with some error messages related to CG.

I'd like to know if there is a way to make ShortcutRecorder works with a ARC environment and Xcode 4.0 or if you use other control to grab user Hotkeys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this fork of ShortCut Recorder:

https://github.com/youknowone/shortcutrecorder

The original appears to have not been updated in some time but I was able to get this fork running on 10.7 without any changes.